# Send multiple files to bash script via Dolphin

Tags: bash, dolphin

I would like to process photos by sending them from Dolphin to bash script with "Open with" feature. But it runs individual instance of the program for each file instead of sending all files to one program instance.

Answer (score 2):

Just enter `command-name %F` into the "Open with" dialogue. The `%F` parameter is substituted with the list of all selected files.